# Does java FileChannnel.transferTo() work cleverly when files are on network?

Tags: java, nio

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html

says

> Bytes can be transferred from a file to some other channel, and vice
>   versa, in a way that can be optimized by many operating systems into a
>   very fast transfer directly to or from the filesystem cache.

If both files are locally on the computer I can understand how this works.

But if the files are on the same network drive does the same apply or not ?

What I mean by this is do the bytes in file2 have to be transferred to local computer first in order to be written to the second file, on a slow network connection this would seem to outweigh any advantages of bypassing the Java heap. Or can the OS say ' Transfer x bytes from file 1 to file 2 and because they are on same drive the actual bytes dont have to be transferred over the network just the instruction to do the transfer'

Comment: If such a mechanism exists, as the documentation says, it is up to the OS to decide; and in turn it means that the implementation by your particular JRE must use the appropriate OS primitives (such as `sendfile()` under Linux for instance).

Comment: but its possible for the OS() to do this though, I couldnt work out if it is feasible or not ?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're actually asking here. The bytes have to be transferred to the operating system in the local computer, and from there over the network to the operating system in the target computer, and from there to the target file. There's no other way it could work. But if the files are on the same network drive you're executing the code on the wrong computer. Execute it on the computer where they are both *local* files.

Comment: @EJP They are on the same network drive but the application will always be installed on the PC connected to the NAS drive rather than on the NAS server itself so I cant execute the code on the right computer (: